# How to prevent .Wait() from mangling the exception?

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-4.5

I've got the following bit of code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    AsyncMain().Wait();
}

private static async Task AsyncMain()
{
    throw new Exception("Panic!");
}
```

In this, the exception will end up showing up in the debugger at Wait() as an aggregate exception. How can I make it show up at the place the exception is thrown?

Comment: Go to Tools -> Exceptions -> Common Language Runtime Exceptions and tick the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

All your async exceptions are "bundled" and thrown as an `AggregateException`. Your original exception is just an inner exception of the `AggregateException`. You can do the following to handle it:

```
private static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        AsyncMain().Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggEx)
    {
        foreach (Exception ex in taskEx.InnerExceptions)
        {
            // Handle your original exception here.
        }
    }
}
```

The reason the `AggregateException` is thrown at the `Wait` is because an exception will **only be caught if it is observed**! This is important to understand, because if you didn't use `Wait` in the above example, the exception would never have occurred.

If you need to catch the exception in `AsyncMain`, then surround it with a try/catch, handling it in the method, otherwise it will always be thrown when and where it is observed.

If you ever have some spare time, read the [Sacha Barber's article series on TPL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152765/Task-Parallel-Library-of-n#handle). Absolutely fantastic. He explains the concepts really well!

Comment: I do not want to handle my exceptions. I already know how to do this. What I'm looking for is how to get the exceptions to break in the debugger on the correct line.

Comment: @Layl, see Yuval's comment on your question

Comment: Apologies @Layl, please see the ammended answer.

Comment: It seems the specific exception I was looking at had some weird settings in visual studio causing weird exception behavior. It has been fixed now through the Exceptions menu suggested by Yuval